# Which sentence is more grammatically correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

The last payment was made on January 31, 2018.

or

The last payment made was on January 31, 2018.

Comment: Either is fine, but there are different nuances to each. It all depends on what you want to emphasize.

Comment: ***The last payment was made on January 31, 2018.***  is correct  but it depend on your scenario, where this sentence is  used

Comment: Both are "correct".

Comment: In case you're interested, your title can use adjusting. When exactly two items are being compared, it's "more" instead of "most". I don't know whether everyone feels that grammar strictly requires that, but in formal use the comparative is used instead of the superlative when the number of items under consideration is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are "grammatically correct", but they mean slightly different things.

**The last payment was made on January 31, 2018** - the final payment of a series was made on that date.

**The last payment [that was] made was on January 31, 2018** - the most recent payment (of a series, or not) was made on that date.

Comment: Please don't answer questions which blatantly don't meet the site standards.

Comment: Please don't use comments for expressions of opinion about matters best resolved by voting or moderation.